# Task Scheduler Task Completes Script Does not Run

Tags: powershell, cmd, taskscheduler

I have a simple powershell job that copies a file from my computer to a network folder. I have verified that it is able to run when manually triggered, but not through task scheduler. When triggering the task from Scheduler the history indicated that it has run as I get both "Action Completed" and "Task Completed".

```
copy C:\test.txt "\\network\folder\destination\" /Z /Y
```

On the job itself:

Action:

-Program/Script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

-Arguments: -file "C:\Users\me\Desktop\move.ps1"

Its allowed to run on demand, running through a user with access to the network folder, with highest privileges. Any trouble shooting ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that the script works when run manually?

Comment: Can the user login to run a batch job? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957131.aspx

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that, was about to update the post.

Comment: You can use Windows PowerShell ISE, which will act as an IDE where you can have breakpoints as well to figure out where your script is debunking and/or any values you may want to check.

Comment: Normally, in PowerShell, `copy` is aliased to `Copy-Item`, which does *not* use the same syntax as the CMD.EXE `copy` command. The switches `/Z /Y` suggest that you are thinking of the CMD.EXE `copy` command, not the `Copy-Item` PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: @ChaseRaab Try changing the line given to: `Copy-Item -Path 'C:\test.txt' -Destination '\\network\folder\destination\' -Force` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a cmd function from PowerShell which has `copy` aliased to the `Copy-Item` cmdlet by default.  You'd need to modify your script to call `cmd` if you want to keep that line as it is.

```
& cmd /c copy C:\test.txt \\network\folder\destination /Z /Y
```